# ACCESS 2013: Trying to update two fields in one table with many from another

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I have a linked table in Access that I want to update from a local table. The problem is that the linked table is used for specifications so it contains one line for each attribute. For example, the two fields used in the linked table are ATTRIBUTE_DESC and ATTRIBUTE_VALUE. Each specification may have multiple descriptions. Here is a sample from the linked table:

```
SPECIFICATION_NO    SPEC_SEQ_NO ATTRIBUTE_DESC    ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
------------------  ----------- ---------------   -----------------
0000000001          10          MANUFACTURER      AMERICAN DARLING
0000000001          15          MODEL             B84B-5
0000000001          20          YEAR MANUFACTURED 2000
0000000001          25          DATE INSTALLED    5/3/1999
0000000001          30          EXTENSION LENGTH    
0000000001          35          MAIN VALVE SIZE   6
0000000001          40          ISOLATION VALVE   DIAMETER  
0000000001          45          ISOLATION VALVE   DIRECTION 
0000000001          50          ISOLATION VALVE   DISTANCE  
0000000001          55          AS BUILT #        C025-106-113
0000000001          60          ENVIRONMENT 
0000000001          65          STR 
0000000001          70          FIVE YEAR PM DUE  OCTOBER 2015
```

The local table has different ATTRIBUTE_VALUES based on the ATTRIBUTE_DESC in the linked table. For example, above the MANUFACTURER might be CLOW instead of AMERICAN DARLING.

The query I created has all of the relevant specification information in the table and I've used the ATTRIBUTE_DESC with different criteria to update the ATTRIBUTE_VALUE.

Unfortunately doing it this way I get an error "Duplicate Output Destination "PROD_SA_SPECIFICATION_DETAILS.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE". So my question is whether there is a better way to update this type of table - either through a different query setup or via VBA. I don't know much VBA so if that is the best answer can I get an example for one of the attributes?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be helpful to actually see your query and desired output. I even wonder about your table design as you don't seem to use normalization into logical groupings but use the [Entity-Attribute-Value structure](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure/20761#20761). I imagine complex queries are used to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

My query is like this:

Table being updated: PROD_SA_SPECIFICATION_DETAILS

Field: ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
Table: PROD_SA_SPECIFICATION_DETAILS
Update to: [UPDATE: SA_SPECIFICATION_DETAILS].[ATTRIBUTE_VALUE]
Criteria: MANUFACTURER

So I have the same for each criteria, none of the criteria are duplicated. In the case above there would be 13 as above with the different criteria. I realize I could use the sequence number since they are different for each spec but we add lines and remove lines on occasion and I'd rather not have to remember to update the query so that wrong information goes in the wrong fields.

I realize that this table is not normalized and that is by design (blame Oracle). It is not normalized because various specifications may be variable lengths, ie some may have 10 lines and some may have 12. There are two parts to this table the other is the SA_SPECIFICATION_DATA which is linked by specification_no.